# How to create a "strobe light" (flashing) effect with a display controlled by Pi?

Tags: display, screen

I've been stuck longer than I'd care to admit trying to find a solution for representing signal data visually with a "strobe light" type of effect or something similar, as a component of a larger IoT project with Pi (v4). It doesn't matter to me if I'm controlling the hardware of the monitor itself or a full screen window that's displayed on the monitor.

I'm just looking for any high-level guidance or examples on how this can be done relatively easily.

So far I've managed to create the effect by using LED's instead of a display. In my efforts to control the display in this way I've explored these approaches:

- pygame

  - could do the job but seems unduly complex and led to some initial unexpected results
- screen-brightness control (Python lib)

  - not exactly what I need and also only works on Windows and possibly some Linux with a lot of work

I am fine with any language or approach, although Python would be easiest to integrate. Ideally, I would be able to control the speed at which the flashing happens as well as the colors (black/white, red/white, etc).

***Update:*** I'm still happy to receive any advice, but I did manage to make some serious progress using `pyglet`. I think it may be the way to go for me.

Comment: use an html file with javacript function that changes the  background color ... view using a web browser

Comment: @jsotola yes I was kind of thinking about that. I’ve done a little Django although it’s been a while. Might give it a try this evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the whole screen to flash it is easy in pygame:

```
import pygame,time

pygame.init()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
r=1
while r<20:
    scr.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    scr.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    r+=1
    
pygame.quit()
```